# The generic type already contains a definition

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors

If I try to define the following `Pair<A, B>` class in C#, I get a compiler error.

```
public class Pair<A, B>
{
    public Pair(A a, B b)
    {
        this.A = a;
        this.B = b;
    }

    public A A { get; }
    public B B { get; }
}
```

The compiler error is:

> ```
> error CS0102: The type 'Pair<A, B>' already contains a definition for 'A'
> error CS0102: The type 'Pair<A, B>' already contains a definition for 'B'
> ```

Where are the conflicting definitions?

Usually, one can define a property with the same name as its type, e.g.:

```
public Guid Guid { get; }
public Uri Uri { get; }
```

Why is the compiler complaining about the names `A` and `B`?

Comment: Despite the problem coming from generic type arguments and not from the naming redundancy of typed variables, I recommend [C# Naming Conventions](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/C-Sharp-coding-standards-and-naming-conventions/) and [C# Coding Standards and Naming Conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md) and [C# Coding Conventions (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions) and books from Robert C. Martin for example

Comment: "Where are the conflicting definitions?" - one in the class declaration `Pair<A, B>`, and one for the property. (Your `Guid` example would be broken if `Guid` were a nested type declared within the same class, which is closer to the situation here.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I *do* feel that I'm missing something really obvious here, but I still don't see it. It's very embarrassing. In the class declaration, `A` and `B` are type parameters, right?

Comment: @MarkSeemann: Yes, and the name of a type parameter is not allowed to be the same as the name of a member of the class.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wow, I've only written C# since 2002, and I didn't know that. Thank you for answering. Is that in the C# spec?

Comment: @MarkSeemann: Yup, I'm adding a link.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're so awesome! I already knew that, but still. Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's specified in the "Class members" section in the C# standard. In the current [draft-v6 branch](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v6/standard/classes.md#1531-general):

> The name of a type parameter in the *type_parameter_list* of a class declaration shall differ from the names of all other type parameters in the same *type_parameter_list* and shall differ from the name of the class and the names of all members of the class.

In other words, you can't get a type parameter the same name as another type parameter or a class member. Here, you have a type parameter called `A` and a property called `A`.

The fact that the type of the property is also `A` is irrelevant; this code gives the same error:

```cs
class Broken<T>
{
    public string T { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow, in that example, the error message suddenly makes sense, too. :D